# Show selected file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, jfilechooser

I want to show selected file that was chosen with `JFileChooser` on `JTextarea` in `JFrame`, like this:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(6, 12);
contentPane.add(textArea);
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
fileChooser.setDialogTitle("XML Datei auswählen");
int ret = fileChooser.showDialog( fileChooser, "auswählen");
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    file3 = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();
    textArea.setText(file3.getName());
```

but it shows me nothing on textarea, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this method

```
int ret = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  String file3 = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
  textArea.setText(file3);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes is simple, possible to replace, change

```
textArea.setText(file3.getName());
```

with

[JTextArea.read(Reader in, Object desc) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)